# Joomla 3.7 override

Tags: overriding, joomla3.7

I am trying to make on component layout override or a custom menu item  on Joomla 3.7.2 but I can not make it work.

I followed the instructions from the documentation https://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla
and I placed “myarticle.php” in the folder 
JPATH_ROOT/templates/beez3/html/com_content/article resulting in the following structure for my files:

```
JPATH_ROOT/templates/beez3/html/com_content/article/default.php
JPATH_ROOT/templates/beez3/html/com_content/article/default_links.php
JPATH_ROOT/templates/beez3/html/com_content/article/myarticle.php
```

(defaut.php and default.php are template overrides files placed by the templates itself).

I expected to see the “myarticle” option at the drop down selection for layouts either on global article options or the article options itself. It did not show up.

The I tried to make a menu item override and according to the same documentation I added one more file “myarticle.xml” resulting to the following structure:

```
JPATH_ROOT/templates/beez3/html/com_content/article/default.php 
JPATH_ROOT/templates/beez3/html/com_content/article/default_links.php
JPATH_ROOT/templates/beez3/html/com_content/article/myarticle.php
JPATH_ROOT/templates/beez3/html/com_content/article/myarticle.xml
```

I expected to see “myarticle” menu item type under “Article” menu types when I tried to ad a new menu  item, but nothing new appeared.

am using this set up:
Joomla 3.7.2, php7.0.9, apache 2.4.23, mariadb 10.1.16.

I don't believe that extensions I have installed on joomla are causing the problem because I am testing it on new article with beez3 template.

But to give you the full picture, the extensions I have installed are:
Chrono Forms5, Contact Map, Phoca Gallery.

I have also installed JD New York Template which is using Gantry 4.23 framework.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance Christoforos

Comment: I dont understand, you want to make a custom menu override? Like, overriding the output of the menu modul?

Comment: I want to make "myarticle" to have a custom rendered output. This can be achieved eiher by layout override or by menu override. The problem is that non of them is working.

Comment: So to be correct, from the menu modul with the layout override you want to make "myarticle" custom style I think. Its possible, make a layout override for menu modul, than copy and rename the default.php to myarticle.php, then edit the myarticle.php to whatever you want, then go to modules > new menu > advanced > layout > and chose the myarticle layout > save.

Comment: I have alredy done this. It is in pararaph 5 of my question

Comment: You dont understand how it works, please read my comment again, or I will explain it. That layout override DO not shows up in Article menu types only in new menu modul > advanced tab > layout > here you will see the myarticle layout
and your menu_modul layout override will be stored is: mysite.com/templates/templatename/html/mod_menu/myarticle.php

Comment: I understand what you meant now, but  don't want to override the whole menu module just the artilcle layout that the  menu item points to. If I understand correct the tutorial the new layout should be avaible at the template stylses drop down

Comment: Okey, so you want to override the ex. the blog-category layout for articles?

Comment: yes but no luck